# sending large text message to Spring MVC Restful service

Tags: spring, rest

I am using spring MVC RESTful service and I am catch large text message from front end which contains characters like \,& and my controller throws an error for large text messages 
I am getting below error

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [validate_webservice] in context with path [/validate_webservice] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.EncodingNotSupportedException: Determine encoding for message. The following is the first 50 chars of the message for reference, although this may not be where the issue is: MSH|^~\\] with root cause
```

ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.EncodingNotSupportedException: Determine encoding for message. The following is the first 50 chars of the message for reference, although this may not be where the issue is: MSH|^~\

How to successfully pass large complex string values?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put CDATA in your large text to avoid XML parsing in the content. Then you can use characters like "<" and "&"... in your content:

```
<![CDATA[ your large complex string values with & < and &.... ]]>
```

More info at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp